# Cannot read property '1' of null cannot register second user to mongo db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, registration

I'm trying to register a new user in MongoDb(atlas) and the register() method works one time, but the second time I try to upload another user it sends me the 500 error, and if I test the endpoint on postman it says 'Cannot read property '1' of null'. On VsCode it says the awaits are invalid, but they worked in the example I cloned this process from.

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await new User({ firstName, lastName, email, password })
    console.log(user)
    await User.register(user, password, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err.message);
        }
        res.json("welcome" + user.firstName + user.lastName);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB changed the definition of the "unique" property from previous versions. In the User model for this collection the indexes had the property of "unique: true" which made them unusable due to Mongo's most recent update[From MongoAtlas website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXMPR.png)